# Convert a NameValueCollection to a dynamic object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to take a FormCollection passed to my ASP.NET MVC Controller and convert it to a dynamic object, which is then serialized as Json and passed to my Web API.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form)
    {
        var api = new MyApiClient(new MyApiClientSettings());

        dynamic data = new ExpandoObject();

        this.CopyProperties(form, data); // I would like to replace this with just converting the NameValueCollection to a dynamic

        var result = api.Post("customer", data);

        if (result.Success)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customer", new { id = result.Response.CustomerId });

        ViewBag.Result = result;

        return View();
    }

    private void CopyProperties(NameValueCollection source, dynamic destination)
    {
        destination.Name = source["Name"];
        destination.ReferenceCode = source["ReferenceCode"];
    }
```

I've seen examples converting a dynamic object to a Dictionary or NameValueValueCollection, but need to go the other way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you say what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm guessing you are asking for two lines of code that turns the collection into a ExpandoObject?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7596697/187697

Comment: I tried to answer your question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858023/how-do-i-access-a-namevaluecollection-like-request-form-or-configurationmanager/43858024#43858024

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick google search turned up this:

http://theburningmonk.com/2011/05/idictionarystring-object-to-expandoobject-extension-method/

So you can do:

```
IDictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Foo", "Bar" } };
dynamic dobj = dict.ToExpando();
dobj.Foo = "Baz";
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes ... just need to convert the NameValueCollection to the Dictionary first.

Answer (score 2):

I have shown how to create and `dynamic dictionary/keyvaluepair` below.  I have add an extension method to convert a dictionary to a `NameValueCollection`.

This works quite well for me but one thing you should be aware of is that Dictionary does not allow duplicate keys and `NameValueCollection` does.  So that could throw an exception if you tried moving to a Dictionary.

```
void Main()
{
    dynamic config = new ExpandoObject();
    config.FavoriteColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    config.FavoriteNumber = 8;
    Console.WriteLine(config.FavoriteColor);
    Console.WriteLine(config.FavoriteNumber);

    var nvc = ((IDictionary<string, object>) config).ToNameValueCollection();
    Console.WriteLine(nvc.Get("FavoriteColor"));
    Console.WriteLine(nvc["FavoriteNumber"]);
    Console.WriteLine(nvc.Count);
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static NameValueCollection ToNameValueCollection<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)
    {
        var nvc = new NameValueCollection();
        foreach(var pair in dict)
        {
            string value = pair.Value == null ? null : value = pair.Value.ToString();
            nvc.Add(pair.Key.ToString(), value);
        }

        return nvc;
    }

}
```