# ASP MVC serializes Dictionary<string,string> differently when attached to model vs JsonResult

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc

I've got a `Dictionary<string,string>` that's attached to my model. When it reaches the client it's deserialized properly into `[{"Text":"bla","Value":"V1"},{"Text":"abc","Value":"V2"}, {"Text":"def","Value":"V3"}]`.

It's being sent by the statement `return View(model);` in my controller.

But when I send the same data down via JsonResult with the following:

```
        var jsonResult = Json(myDictionary, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return jsonResult;
```

It comes out like this:

```
{V1: "{ Value = V1, Text = bla }", V2: "{ Value = V2, Text = abc }", V3: "{ Value = V3, Text = def }"}
```

Is there a way to fix this in .NET or do I have to parse this and reconstruct it into something useful in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You could map your `Dictionaty<string, string>` into a new `object`, and then return it using Json:

Mapping: (from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7596697/6539189))

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Property", "foo" } };
var convertedObject = new ExpandoObject();
var eoColl = (ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)convertedObject;

foreach (var kvp in dict)
    eoColl.Add(kvp);    

dynamic eoDynamic = convertedObject;
```

And then return it by JSON (as you are already doing):

```
return Json(convertedObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And receive in your JavaScript like an normal object:

```
{
    V1: "bar",
    V2: "foo",
    V3: "caa"
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you you return `eoDynamic` instead of `convertedObject`? Otherwise I'm not sure I understand the point of `dynamic eoDynamic = convertedObject;`

Comment: Also, `myDictionary` is of type `Dictionary<string,string>` and `convertedObject` is being cast to `KeyValuePair<string,object>`, so `eoColl.Add(kvp);` doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think this can work, the problem is in the way the `Dictionary` stores the value. It's stored as `kvp.Value = "{ Prop1 = key, Prop2 = key - value }"`