# How to access the global variables from the requirejs module?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I defined a module (for the code easy to read,I delete some unnecessary line..)

Here is my `game.js`

```
define(['util'], function (util) {
    return {
        createNew : function (setting) {
            var game = {
                intervalTrigger : function () {
                    return window.setInterval(function () {
                        score++;//how to read deal with this value?
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        };
        return game;
    }
};
});
```

and use it in `app.js`:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "./src",
});

requirejs(['util', 'game'],
    function (util,game) {
        var score = 0;

        function startgame(level) {
            var setting = {};
            var g = game.createNew();
            g.intervalTrigger();
        }
        startgame(0);
    });
```

in my case, I need to `createNew`  for few times, so the score can't be stored in the module.

so how to access `score` in the module `game`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `score` as an actual module. For example:

```
define([], function() {
      var gameStats = {
           score: 0
      };

      return gameStats;
});
```

Now you just need to inject wherever you need to work with game stats.

Answer (score 0):

create a get/set function and expose it in the game.js:

```
define(['util'], function (util) {
    var score = 0;
    return {
        createNew : function (setting) {
            var game = {

                intervalTrigger : function () {
                    return window.setInterval(function () {                     
                      score++;//how to read deal with this value?
                    }, 1000);
                }
                getScore: function(){ return score;} //getting the score
                setScore: function(value){score = value;} //setting the score
                }

            };
            return game;

        }
    };
});
```

now here you can use:

```
        require.config({
          baseUrl: "./src",
    });
requirejs(['util', 'game'],
        function   (util,game) {
            var score = 0;

            function startgame(level) {
                var setting = {};
                var g = game.createNew();
                g.setScore(score); //setting the score
                g.intervalTrigger();
            }
            startgame(0);
     });
```

Comment: wouldn't be better to define score as an actual getter/setter and access it this way? `this.score++`?

Comment: not if you want to have validations on the set method

Comment: Hi Matias, I know about them just didn't think about it when gave the answer :)

Comment: Uhmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm

Comment: I doubt it. Check your statement: **not if you want to have validations on the set method**... Humility is a plus here :(

Comment: omg you are pathetic.. you exactly showed that you have no humility. yes ecma script 5 getters and setters are so over my head.. I don't know what they are, please teach me master. how do I use defineProperty

Comment: So why you say "not if you want to have validations on set method" if you know that you can define a setter..............................

Comment: Nevermind, if you already knew it who knows why you're still using getters/setters as regular functions (you might argue that you do for older browsers...). BTW, again, nevermind.

Comment: Have you downvoted my answer as a vengance to my comments? ;O

Comment: I've double-checked your "I'm patethic" statement, and it seems like I think that humility is still important in your case. Do I need to teach `Object.defineProperty`? Who said you need this? Your `getScore: function(){ return score;} //getting the score` can be turned into `get score() { return score; }`. I don't see an `Object.defineProperty`!!!!!!

Comment: In the other hand, I've checked that both downvotes here on my answer and on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943817/mapping-object-to-dictionary-and-vice-versa/4944547#4944547 where made in the same minute and after some moments you added the "omg you're pathetic" comment. At least, I've not downvoted your answer and I've tried to suggest you how to improve your answer. Anyway, I'm not here for the points, I love contributing with content, that's all.