# How Do i pass form values from a Dictionary <String, String> to an Object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

I am getting Values from a form in a Dictionary. 
Key equals field on the page and value is what the user has supplied .Is there a better way to pass the values to an object as below :I am new to this so will appreciate your help . Thanks for your help
I get the values using the following call :

```
public async void PostFormData()
```

Now I am trying to pass the values from the dictionary to an Object as below .
The method below is very elementary and I am looking to make this more dynamic .

```
public static void ConverttoObject()
                {
                    Dictionary<string, string> test = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                    test.Add("Name", "Daniel");
                    test.Add("LastName", "Wong");
                    test.Add("Zip", "60004");
                    test.Add("City", "New York");


                    var abc = new FormInfo();

                    foreach (var key in test.Keys)
                    {
                        foreach (var val in test.Values)
                        {
                            if (key.Equals("Name"))
                                abc.Name = val;
                            else if (key.Equals("LastName"))
                                abc.City = val;
                            else if (key.Equals("Zip"))
                                abc.Zip = val;
                            else if (key.Equals("City"))
                                abc.City = val;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            public class FormInfo
            {
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public string LastName { get; set; }
                public string Zip { get; set; }
                public string City { get; set; }

            }
```

Comment: What do you mean _getting form values from javascript in Dictionary_? What is you client side code. How are you posting the form values. What is the signature of your POST method?

Comment: foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
               {

                   foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
                   {
                       
                       Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, val));

                                           
                     
                   }
               }

Comment: If your POST method is `public ActionResult Edit(Form model)` then  the model is correctly bound for you. What is it that you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to POST from to server Side .I am using public async void PostFormData()

Comment: Your not making any sense. There is no such thing as a Dictionary in javascript. And what is your javascript? Edit you question to explain what it is you trying to do. If your submitting a form based on typeof `Form`, and you method has a parameter for `Form`, then its all bound by the framework.

Comment: Sorry about that , I have edited my question and added more details . I understand the confusion . Thanks

Comment: I think you're still missing something. Just make your action method `public ActionResult Edit(FormInfo model)`  and MVC will handle it all for you automatically - just make sure the form field names (or Json properties) match the property names on the object and you're done.

Comment: I think you need to go to the MVC site and work through some tutorials to understand the basics of MVC

Comment: Have a read through [this article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx), it explains model binding and shows a number of approaches that vary from very manual (still simpler than what you're attempting) all the way through to near-automatic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your own extension method to convert a dictionary to an object like this one:

```
public static class IDictionaryExtensions
{
    public static T ToObject<T>(this IDictionary<string, object> source)
        where T : class, new()
    {
        T someObject = new T();
        Type someObjectType = someObject.GetType();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in source)
        {
            someObjectType.GetProperty(item.Key).SetValue(someObject, item.Value, null);
        }

        return someObject;
    }
}
```

Solution approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943817/mapping-object-to-dictionary-and-vice-versa).

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do:

```
abc.Name = test["Name"];
abc.LastName = test["LastName"];
abc.Zip = test["Zip"];
abc.City = test["City"];
```