# Cast dynamic object to type using reflection c#

Tags: c#, reflection

Consider the following code

```
 var currentType = Type.GetType("Some.Type, Some");
 dynamic myDynamic = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
 myDynamic.A = "A";
 var objectInCorrectType = ???
```

How do I cast the dynamic to the currentType?

Comment: You can't. You either do a reinterpretation cast, which basically says "I know this reference is really an X masquerading as Y, so cast it to X for me, reinterpreting the reference as a reference to X", or you do a conversion which involves code that does the conversion, such as creating a new X and copying over values, etc. There is no built-in way to convert or cast from an ExpandoObject to some specific type, you need to build that yourself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't cast a dynamic object to a specific type, as @Lasse commented.

However, your question mentions "reflection", so I suspect you're looking for a way to simply map property values (i.e. "creating a new X and copying over values, etc." in Lasse's comment):

```
...
myDynamic.A = "A";

// get settable public properties of the type
var props = currentType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Where(x => x.GetSetMethod() != null);

// create an instance of the type
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(currentType);

// set property values using reflection
var values = (IDictionary<string,object>)myDynamic;
foreach(var prop in props)
    prop.SetValue(obj, values[prop.Name]);
```

Comment: I would exclude properties.Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0) or you'll also include indexers. And I also believe _GetSetMethod_ is not guaranteed public, even though you requested BindingFlags.Public, since a property is a proxy for a getter and setter method, which may have different access modifiers.

Answer (score 9):

`dynamic` is [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) a variable (i.e. delaying type check to run-time). It still holds a typed object but it's not checked during compile-time.

Thus, since an `ExpandoObject` is a type either if you assign it to a typed or dynamic reference, you can't cast or convert an `ExpandoObject` to a type just because it shares the same members as the target type.

BTW, since `ExpandoObject` implements `IDictionary<string, object>`, you can implement some kind of on-the-fly mapping from the `ExpandoObject` instance to target type where a member matches as an extension method:

```
public static class ExpandObjectExtensions
{
    public static TObject ToObject<TObject>(this IDictionary<string, object> someSource, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
           where TObject : class, new ()
    {
        Contract.Requires(someSource != null);
        TObject targetObject = new TObject();
        Type targetObjectType = typeof (TObject);

        // Go through all bound target object type properties...
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in 
                    targetObjectType.GetProperties(bindingFlags))
        {
            // ...and check that both the target type property name and its type matches
            // its counterpart in the ExpandoObject
            if (someSource.ContainsKey(property.Name) 
                && property.PropertyType == someSource[property.Name].GetType())
            {
                property.SetValue(targetObject, someSource[property.Name]);
            }
        }

        return targetObject;
    }
}
```

Now, try the following code and it'll work as you expect:

```
public class A 
{
    public int Val1 { get; set; }
}

// Somewhere in your app...
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.Val1 = 11;

// Now you got a new instance of A where its Val1 has been set to 11!
A instanceOfA = ((ExpandoObject)expando).ToObject<A>();
```

*Actually, I've based this answer on other Q&A where I could address a similar issue of mapping objects to dictionary and viceversa: [Mapping object to dictionary and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943817/mapping-object-to-dictionary-and-vice-versa/4944547#4944547)*.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because I needed to take a class like this:

```
public class PropertyChange
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("arrayValue")]
    public dynamic[] PropertyArray { get; set; }
}
```

and convert the `PropertyArray` property of an object (deserialized from JSON using the Newtonsoft library) into an array of objects of a specific type where the type can be derived from the `PropertyName`.

I wrote this helper class called `DynamicCast<>` and decided to post it here in case anyone else in in the same situation as me.

This helper class allows you to write code like this:

```
public class MyType
{
    public string A { get; set; }
}

var myCast = new DynamicCast<MyType>();

dynamic dyn = ExpandoObject();
dyn.A = "Hello";

var myType = myCast.Cast(dyn);
Console.WriteLine(myType.A); // prints 'Hello'
```

This is an example of how I used it to solve my deserialization problem:

```
public class JsonTest
{
    [JsonProperty("theArray")]
    public dynamic[] TheArray { get; set; }
}

var json = "{'theArray':[{'a':'First'},{'a':'Second'}]}";
var jsonTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonTest>(json);

var myCast = new DynamicCast<MyType>();
var myTypes = myCast.Cast(jsonTest.TheArray).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(myTypes[0].A); // prints 'First'
```

The wrote the `DynamicCast` class based on other answers here. It looks like this:

```
public class DynamicCast<T> where T: class, new()
{
    private Property[] _proprties;

    public DynamicCast()
    {
        _proprties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(x => x.GetSetMethod() != null)
            .Where(x => x.GetGetMethod() != null)
            .Select(p =>
            {
                var property = new Property
                {
                    PropertyInfo = p,
                    Name = p.Name
                };
                foreach (var attribute in p.GetCustomAttributes(false))
                {
                    if (attribute.GetType() == typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute))
                    {
                        var jsonProperty = (JsonPropertyAttribute)attribute;
                        property.Name = jsonProperty.PropertyName;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (attribute.GetType() == typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute))
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                return property;
            })
            .Where(p => p != null)
            .ToArray();
    }

    public T Cast(IDictionary<string, object> d)
    {
        var t = new T();
        Fill(d, t);
        return t;
    }

    public T Cast(JObject d)
    {
        var t = new T();
        Fill(d, t);
        return t;
    }

    public dynamic Cast(T t)
    {
        dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
        Fill(t, d);
        return d;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Cast(IEnumerable<JObject> da)
    {
        return da.Select(e => Cast(e));
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Cast(IEnumerable<object> da)
    {
        return da.Select(e =>
        {
            if (e is JObject) return Cast((JObject)e);
            if (e is IDictionary<string, object>) return Cast((IDictionary<string, object>)e);
            return null;
        });
    }

    public void Fill(IDictionary<string, object> values, T target)
    {
        foreach (var property in _proprties)
            if (values.TryGetValue(property.Name, out var value))
                property.PropertyInfo.SetValue(target, value, null);
    }

    public void Fill(JObject values, T target)
    {
        foreach (var property in _proprties)
        {
            if (values.TryGetValue(property.Name, out var value))
            {
                if (value is JValue jvalue)
                {
                    var propertyValue = Convert.ChangeType(jvalue.Value, property.PropertyInfo.PropertyType);
                    property.PropertyInfo.SetValue(target, propertyValue, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Fill(T obj, IDictionary<string, object> target)
    {
        foreach (var property in _proprties)
            target[property.Name] = property.PropertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
    }

    private class Property
    {
        public PropertyInfo PropertyInfo;
        public string Name;
    }
}
```

You can try this out for yourself in .Net Fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/J1JXgU