# Get nested properties name,value pair in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I have following classes.

```
public class AlloyDock
{
    public int LeftA { get; set; }
    public int RightA { get; set; }
}

public class Charger
{
    public int LeftC { get; set; }
    public int RightC { get; set; }
}
public class VehicleControlTest
{
    public Charger Charger1 { get; set; }
}
public class BasicControlTest
{
    public AlloyDock AlloyDock1 { get; set; }
}
class Appointment
{
    public BasicControlTest BasicControlTest1 { get; set; }
    public VehicleControlTest VehicleControlTest1 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get name, value pair of leaf children in form of dictionary from list of objects of appointments.

Resultant data should be in pair list <"PropertyName", "Value"> form:

<"LeftA", 123>, <"RightA", 123>,<"RightA", 12113>, <"LeftA", 1323>

I am following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943817/mapping-object-to-dictionary-and-vice-versa) but its not returning desired results.

Help needed.

Comment: Your dictionary will have duplicate keys.

Comment: May be we can use list of pair objects.