# Wrap mapping of string value to object property

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, properties, mapping

Having following blocks of code, is there an elegant way to wrap them up to reduce redundancy of codes, such as the repeating `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` and the checking of *"1"* or *"0"* for mapping of the *boolean* field. Is it possible to put them inside a dictionary first and first and write a method to map the dictionary to the `model` properties. Something like this: [Mapping object to dictionary and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943817/mapping-object-to-dictionary-and-vice-versa)
but the problem is different property of `model` is having different datatype

```
 string[] stringValue = data.Split(',');
 model.Field1 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue[4].Trim()) ? 0 : int.Parse(stringValue[4].Trim());
 model.Field2 = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue[5].Trim()) && (stringValue[5].Trim() == "1");
 model.Field3 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue[6].Trim()) ? null : stringValue[6].Trim();
 model.Field4 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue[7].Trim()) ? 0 : int.Parse(stringValue[7].Trim());
 model.Field5 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue[8].Trim()) ? 0 : int.Parse(stringValue[8].Trim());
 model.Field6 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue[9].Trim()) ? 0 : int.Parse(stringValue[9].Trim());
 model.Field7 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue[10].Trim()) ? 0 : int.Parse(stringValue[10].Trim());
 model.Field8 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue[11].Trim()) ? 0 : int.Parse(stringValue[11].Trim());
 model.Field9 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue[12].Trim()) ? 0 : int.Parse(stringValue[12].Trim());
 model.Field10 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue[13].Trim()) ? 0 : int.Parse(stringValue[13].Trim());
 model.Field11 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue[14].Trim()) ? null : stringValue[14].Trim();
 model.Field12 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue[15].Trim()) ? null : stringValue[15].Trim();
 model.Field13 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue[16].Trim()) ? 0 : double.Parse(stringValue[16].Trim());
 model.Field14 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue[17].Trim()) ? 0 : int.Parse(stringValue[17].Trim());
 model.Field15 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue[18].Trim()) ? 0 : double.Parse(stringValue[18].Trim());
 model.Field16 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue[19].Trim()) ? 0 : double.Parse(stringValue[19].Trim());
 model.Field17 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue[20].Trim()) ? null : stringValue[20].Trim();
 model.Field18 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue[21].Trim()) ? 0 : double.Parse(stringValue[21].Trim());
 model.Field19 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue[22].Trim()) ? 0 : double.Parse(stringValue[22].Trim());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write some extension methods to wrap things for you, for example:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static int GetIntValue(this string orig)
    {
        var trimmed = orig?.GetTrimmedValue();
        return trimmed == null ? 0 : int.Parse(trimmed);
    }

    public static string GetTrimmedValue(this string orig)
    {
        var trimmed = orig?.Trim();
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmed) ? null : trimmed;
    }
}
```

Then you can call them from any string:

```
var x = "1 ";
int y = x.GetIntValue();

var i = "Hi ";
string j = i.GetTrimmedValue();
```