# Convert Dapper IDictionary into a Class?

Tags: c#, dictionary, dapper

Is it possible to convert an IDictionary into a class?

My IDictionary looks like this

```
{{DapperRow,   
 Date = '9/25/2014 12:00:00 AM',    
 UserId = '123456',    
 User = 'Timothy'    
}}
```

my class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public string User {get; set;}
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public virtual someModel {get; set;}    
}
```

Comment: Why do you even have a dictionary? Can you show the code for how you get that?

Comment: How do you retrieve this? Why not use eg `connection.Query<MyClass>(..)` ?

Comment: Did you use `connection.Query<dynamic>()` perhaps? Dapper's job is to load results *and* generate the DTOs you passed as a type parameter. When you *don't* specify a specific type, it will generate an dynamic object that's derived from [DynamicObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.dynamicobject?view=netframework-4.7.2). You can access individual properties directly if you use `dynamic` as the variable type.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943817/mapping-object-to-dictionary-and-vice-versa/4944547

Comment: @ManojChoudhari it's not. This is a question about Dapper, not dictionaries in general.

Comment: The reason you see an `IDictionary<string,object>` in *some* Dapper questions is that custom dynamic objects typically use a Dictionary<string,object> internally which they also expose through `IDictionary<string,object>`. Check for example [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.7.2). Casting the dynamic object to a dictionary allows reading the column names

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Correct that is exactly how I got this Idictionary

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Also I cant explicity use Query<MyClass> as I need to use this same query for at least 30 different classes. So I gather the data using <dynamic> then I need to map it to a it's respective class after the SQL returns its results..

Comment: @CodeMan03 post your code. If you need that conversion, you already know the correct type and so you *can* use `Query<MyClass>`. The query you refer to is a sql string after all. Nothing prevents you from using it with different type arguments. If you mean you have a *function* that calls `Query<T>` which you want to reuse, make it generic as well

Comment: @CodeMan03 with a `dynamic` object you can access any of the existing members the same way you'd access the members of another class. You can write `result.Date` or `result.User` to get the property values

Answer (score 0):

To convert the dictionary you provided to the class you provided, you can just add a constructor to the model class to read the dictionary values.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public MyClass(IDictionary<string, object> data)
    {
        Date = DateTime.Parse(data["Date"].ToString());
        User = data["User"].ToString();
        UserId = int.Parse(data["UserId"].ToString());
    }
}
```

But Panagiotis is right, in this situation you should be taking advantage of dapper to automagically map data to your models for you. Their [readme](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Readme.md) is incredibly helpful if you need to figure out how it works or how to do complex mappings.